# Change child style on parent hover, with :after

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a link inside it, and an animated underline for said link. [Code used from here, (example).](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-sliding-underline/)

To make sure the underline was not huge and far below the text, I applied the animation to the text itself. The problem with this is the hover radius is to small, and I would like the entire button to be able to trigger the animation.

Here is my css and html:

```css
.menuButtonText {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.menuButtonText:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.menuButtonText:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}

.menuButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuButton"><a class="menuButtonText">MenuButton</a>
</div>
<div class="menuButton"><a class="menuButtonText">MenuButton</a>
</div>
<div class="menuButton menuButtonSelected"><a class="menuButtonText">MenuButton</a>
</div>
```

The "menuButton" class is the parent and much larger than the space the text takes up, which is the trigger I wanted, I can't seem to get other solutions to work, and I'm assuming thats because of the ":after".

Comment: just keep the hover to the parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/19mdzLdk/

I added this css:

```
.menuButton:hover .menuButtonText:after {
   width: 100%;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}
```

Now on div hover, the text underlines.